# How to clone HTML select tag and change its ID in the process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am able to change ID's of all other fields except `toCity`. How can I change its ID when I clone it? With my current code, the dropdown is created with the same data, but the ID remains unchanged.

How can I change the ID when I clone?

```js
var toAddCloneCount = 1;

function AddDestination() {
    var clone = $("#toAdd").clone(true);
    clone.find("#days").prop('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
    clone.find("#toDate").attr('id', 'toDate' + toAddCloneCount);
    clone.find('#toCity').prop('id', 'toCity' + toAddCloneCount);
    clone.show();
    clone.attr('id', 'toAdd' + toAddCloneCount++).insertAfter("#toAdd");
    clone.appendTo("#destinations");
}
```

```html
<div id="destinations">
    <div id="toAdd">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style8">To </td>
                <td>
                    <select runat="server" id="toCity" name="toCity"></select>
                </td>
                <td>Days to Stay</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="days" type="number" min="1"  onkeypress="return false" onkeydown="return false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        Date:         
                        <input id="toDate" type="text" class="getCurrentDate"   onkeypress="return false" onkeydown="return false" />
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="AddDestination();" >Add+</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to change the name as well

Comment: I'm not an asp guy but i guess this is because of `runat="server"` which then change ID client side

Comment: I think you got the answer at the same question (posted by you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202042/how-to-make-clone-of-dropdown-with-data-bound-it-too, here isn't code debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = document.getElementById('id_here');
var options = source.innerHTML;
var copy = document.createElement("Select"); 
copy.id = "copy_id"
copy.innerHTML = copy.innerHTML + options;
document.body.appendChild(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generate new id & name for elements:

```
$("button").click(function () {
var num = ($("div[id^='cloneItem_']").length + 1);
//alert(num);
$("#cloneItem_1").clone().insertAfter($("div[id^='cloneItem_']").last()).attr("id", 'cloneItem_' + num).find("select").each(function () {

    $(this).prop({
        'id': function (_, id) {
            id = id.substring(0, id.indexOf('_') + 1);
            return id + num;
        },
            'name': function (_, name) {
            name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('_') + 1);
            return name + num;
        },
            'value': ''
    });

});
```

});

go to the fiddle demo : [clone select element](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragraninga/sbmchtmL/)

Comment: dropdownlist is bonded with data... still id remains same